# Question on How to Separate Meshes Into Multiple, Disconnected Meshes

Tags: mesh, objects

So I'm very new to Blender and was looking to use it to create some sword fight/lightsaber fight actions scenes. However, I'm running into issues with separating body parts for models.

For example, let's say Luke's hand gets cut off by Darth Vader. How do I go about detaching his hand from the rest of his body so that it can be lying on the ground, separate from the rest of his model? I believe that essentially I'd be creating a new model or mesh, but I'm not certain how to do this from an existing mesh.

Any help or links to tutorials would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enter in edit mesh, deselect all, move the mouse over the object that you want to separate, use "L" as a shortcut and you will have a select option. After you select what you want to separate use "P" as shortcut and click on separate. Repeat this for every object that you want to separate.